# swift text label update weekly

Tags: ios, swift

I am a beginner of for swift.

In the homeviewController, I declare a label

```
    @IBOutlet weak var text: UILabel!
```

How can I update this number by 1 from 0 each week from the day the app is installed?

Comment: I just found a post tell you how to run code in background https://www.raywenderlich.com/92428/background-modes-ios-swift-tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, store the launch date somewhere the first time the app launches, for example NSUserDefaults: `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(NSDate(), forKey: "installDate")`. Then, whenever you need to show the label just find the difference in weeks between the current time and the stored one:

```
let installDate = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("installDate") as NSDate!
let today = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let unitFlags = NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfYear
let dateComponents = calendar.components(unitFlags, fromDate:installDate,  toDate:today, options: NSCalendarOptions.MatchNextTime)
let weeks = dateComponents.weekOfYear
```

Comment: What if I want to add 1 each week instead of calculating the difference, is that still possible to do that?

Comment: You'd have to run code every week then, to update the label. The user would have to open your app at least once a week for it to update.

Answer (score -1):

Use `NSUserDefaults` to track the date you updated the `text`

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(NSDate(), forKey: "lastUpdate")
```

Then in method `shouldUpdateTheLabel`:

```
func shouldUpdateLabel() {
    let lastUpdatedSetting = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("lastUpdate") as? NSDate

    var shouldUpdate = true
    if let lastUpdated = lastUpdatedSetting where NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(lastUpdated) < 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 {
            shouldUpdate = false
    }

    if shouldUpdate {
       text.text = "someTextYouWant"
       //Update your label here
       NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(NSDate(), forKey: "lastUpdate")
      //Record the date you update your label
    }else {
        return
    }

}
```